# Debugging in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Is there a way to debug a specific function without knowing where it is?

For example you have a project that has 100 000 lines of code on a lot of files. To find some function that's triggered by some button you need to search a long time and then you put the break point. Is there some tools to do that when I click the button automatic to stop the debugger of Google Chrome?

Comment: Not sure about Chrome, but Firefox has an `ev` button next to elements with event listeners in the HTML Inspector. This button shows all the event listeners bound to that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right side of the Sources Tab look for `Event Listener Breakpoints`, expand the Mouse events, and select the click event, chrome will go into debugger mode every time there's a click event

Answer (score 0):

You can check on the `console` tab what triggers your error, and what will be the files involved.

Here's an example on Chrome :

[Chrome console example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FXUv.png)

On the left, you got the file involved (VM998 for example) and the corresponding line (3, for example).

Hope it helps.